# raster2pgsql populates wrong authority

Tags: postgis, epsg

I'm trying to load a raster in .tif format that is in [EPSG 42303](https://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/7965/). I use the following

```
raster2pgsql -d -C -M -I -s 42303 -t 100x100 filename.tif schemaname.tablename | psql -d dbname -U username
```

The PostGIS table then has a SRID of 42303, per `ST_SRID(rast)`. However, in the `spatial_ref_sys` table, SRID 42303 does not exist. Rather, [97965 appears to be the correct SRID](https://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/7965/postgis/) for PostGIS (by authority sr-org rather than EPSG), and the values in `spatial_ref_sys` for 97965 match what I expect.

The raster views correctly in QGIS regardless. But when I try and correct the SRID to 97965 as follows:

UPDATE tablename set rast= ST_SetSRID(rast, 97965) ;

the raster no longer projects correctly in QGIS.

How can I get the projection to register correctly in PostGIS?

Comment: As you have noticed, code 42303 is not an EPSG code http://www.epsg-registry.org/. You could still try to add that as a fake code into your own PostGIS db with a modified insert SQL  `...values ( 42303, 'epsg', 42303,...`.   Not sure if it helps.

Comment: PostGIS and QGIS need to agree on what the SRID means. Does QGIS know about 97965 (or 42303, or whatever that projection is)?

Comment: @user30184 That's one possibility, but I would like to avoid populating my spatial_ref_sys table with "fake" codes in case this causes problems with future datasets.

Comment: What problems do you suppose to meet?

Comment: If I load a dataset in the future that has a "real" 42303 code. Maybe I could just delete the spatial_ref_sys entry after reprojecting. But I'd also like to understand how the SRID codes are interpreted differently by raster2pgsql and PostGIS.